# How to create this particular graph in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I am new to R and I am using R in RStudio. I recently came across this graph (please see image below) in an R book (although it did not explain how this graph was achieved):

[image: R Graph]

I want to replicate this graph with the following data:

Serial Number of observations (to appear on the x-axis): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Value for each observation: 140, 165, 125, 175, 185

Average Budget Value (will be the horizontal line in the graph): 150

How do I go about creating this graph?

Comment: Just for giggles, here's a base R version - `with(dat, plot(x, val, pch=19, panel.first={abline(h=150); segments(x,val,x,150)}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, val=c(140, 165, 125, 175, 185), mean=150)
dat <- dat %>% gather(var, budget, val:mean)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, budget, group=as.factor(x))) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=150) + 
    geom_point(data=dat %>% filter(var=="val"))
```

[image]

To insert in the difference between point and mean:

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
        group_by(x) %>% 
        summarise(val=diff(budget)*-1, mean=mean(budget)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, budget, group=as.factor(x))) + 
    geom_line(linetype="dotted") + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=150) + 
    geom_point(data=dat %>% filter(var=="val")) + 
    geom_text(data=dat2, aes(x+.1, mean, label=val))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Is it feasible to have a dotted line connecting the points to the average line?

Answer (score 3):

You can do most of the heavy lifting with `geom_segment`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, 
                  y = c(140, 165, 125, 175, 185)), 
       aes(x, y, xend = x, yend = 150, label = y - 150)) + 
    geom_point(color = 'seagreen') + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 150, color = 'seagreen') + 
    geom_segment(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'seagreen') + 
    geom_text(nudge_x = .1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works beautifully!